# Write variables into an html file

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, forms

Have a .net site and I am trying to get a copy of the form in html saved to the server when they are done. Problem is how do I get it to save the data onto a html document without having to write the whole thing again. I got this far when I realized this.

```
        string activeDir = @"c:\Code";
        DateTime time = DateTime.Now;              
        string folformat = "MMdyy";
        string filformat = "hmsMMdyy";
        string fdate = time.ToString(folformat);
        string newPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(activeDir, fdate);
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(newPath);
        string newFileName = time.ToString(filformat)+".html";
        newPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(newPath, newFileName);
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(newPath))
        {
            TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(newPath);
            tw.WriteLine(700linesofhtml);
        }
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, what is the question, but instead of the if you could use

```
File.AppendAllText(string path, string content)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356.aspx

Comment: I have an html form with text boxes A,B and C. How can I get the form with the values of A,B and C written to a new html file without having to rewrite the whole code.

Comment: you need to transform postback form data to "human readable" string (html file)?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: try reading form data from Request.Form collection, so you can format it to some StringBuilder and output to file.